# Execute a script on startup of SUSE reboot

Tags: linux, shell, startup

I'm trying to execute a script called "testing" on startup of my SUSE reboot. So I placed this simple script to '/etc/init.d' 
The code is like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# ScriptName=testing
cat > ~/output << "EOF"
This text is generated on startup!!
EOF
```

After that, I execute these command

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/testing   
touch /etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S12testing
```

But after I reboot the system, nothing happened.

There must be something I missed out.

[Here is the reference I searched.](https://superuser.com/questions/126106/how-to-execute-a-shell-script-on-startup)

Comment: Try making the path absolute (i.e. don't start the path with `~/`, instead do something like `/output`). The tilde uses the current user's home directory, however, since this script is executing at startup, with no users logged in, that's probably not a directory you were expecting.

Comment: *with no users logged in, that's probably not a directory you were expecting*. => It doesn't depend on users logged in, but on the UID with which the process is executed. Since startup scripts are run as root, so this will be /root/output (~ expands to the home directory of root, which is the user for UID 0).

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/testing   
touch /etc/init.d/rc.d/rc3.d/S12testing
```

Should not be 'touch', but a symbolic link (ln -s) to /etc/init.d/testing.

Try

```
cd /etc/init.d/rc.d/rc3.d
ln -s ../../testing S12testing
```

Hope this helps.